# set cron job from php

Tags: php, cron

I try To set `cron` job from `php` but every time i try the code blow it's not work.
tell me what is the problem with this code

```
    $cron = $this->generator();
    file_put_contents("cron.txt", $cron);
    shell_exec('crontab cron.txt');
```

generator function make cron job string like below

```
12 1 * * * /usr/bin/sample >/dev/null 2>&1
```

the cron.txt file is fine. it contain the string but shell_exec some how not working

Comment: Do you have any error?

Comment: Running the script through web server? If yes I assume web server doesn't have privileges to run crontab.

Comment: shell_exec() is closed as default .. are you sure it is enabled

Comment: i use exec and system command they don't worked either

Comment: @Rominux, using my sample using exec with its output (and even the return) value you might be able to log or print some useful detail on your environment. if it helps you also can use 'sudo -u yourWebUser' to run the script to see whats the result once your web-server try the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after many search in Dr Google i found out the answer
i have to change the use to Apache user which is `www-data`
so the command change to `crontab -u www-data cron.txt`

Answer (score 1):

Running your scrip with the hardcoded *$corn* locally works fine for me, i've included a couple of lines to clear the crontab in the beginning and couple of line to confirm the entry. see bellow.

```
$cron = '12 1 * * * /usr/bin/sample >/dev/null 2>&1';

file_put_contents('cron.txt', $cron);

shell_exec('crontab -r');
shell_exec('crontab cron.txt');

// To check the result
$output = []; 
exec('crontab -l',$output);
print_r($output);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 12 1 * * * /usr/bin/sample >/dev/null 2>&1
)
```

And here is a way to check the result of the `crontab cron.txt` execution:

```
$output = $return = [];
exec('crontab cron.txt',$output, $return);
var_dump($output, $return);
```

There will be no output nor return in case of success:

```
array(0) {
}
int(0)
```

Comment: Nop .. It's not work for me ..  think  there might be privilage problem with `apache` server .. because when i use exact same file from my terminal it's worked fine

Comment: Most likely, you have to identify if a. your web-server has the permission to write the cron.txt, let sat you can check the file and its content manually. b. if the web-server has permission to run crontab. in case of failure on the first point i'm getting something like `PHP Warning:  file_put_contents(cron.txt): failed to open stream: Permission denied ....`

Comment: Yes I get Exact Same Error recently you just wrote ... but cron file create and edited perfectly ....

Comment: In that case there is chance the cron.txt file was created by another user. and now the runner doesn't have the privilege to amend it. if this is the case you might be able to solve it by manually remove the file and make sure next time you scrip runs by your web-server user first (i.e. not running it as a php scrip locally)

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping me .. i found the solution... all i have to do is identify the user for `crontab` like below
`crontab -u www-data cron.txt`

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the apache server will run as a separate limited resource account that rightfully should not create cron jobs. This is a pretty easy way to get the host server compromised. Especially if this is running in a publicly accessible ip address space.

However, if the environment is secure and your server administrator allows, you can have the apache process either run as a higher privileged account (yours for example) or to use the suexec feature to run as a designated account with limited but appropriate permissions.